# File attachment not attaching phpMailer

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

It's my first trying to use phpMailer and I am not receiving any attachments with it. Everything else gets sent but the attachment.
The `uploads` directory is right after the root where the attached file should be. Is there something wrong with my php form.

```
<?php

require('class.phpmailer.php');

//var_dump($_POST);

//die;

$subject = "Consignment Form";

$name = $_POST['name'];

$email_address = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];


$target_dir = "/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);

// put your email

$to = 'gslonina7@gmail.com';


$email_subject = "Consignment form submitted by:  $name"; 

// create email body and send it

$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".

    "Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ".

    "Email: $email_address\n \nPhone: $phone \n".

    "Message: $message \n ";


$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = $email_address;
$email->FromName  = $name;
$email->Subject   = $email_subject;
$email->Body      = $email_body;
$email->AddAddress( 'gslonina7@gmail.com' );
$email->AddAttachment( $target_file );

return $email->Send();

?>

<form role="form" action="mail_consignment_new.php" class="contact-form validation-engine ajax-send">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="input_name">Name *</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control validate[required]" id="input_name" placeholder="Name *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="input_email">Email *</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control validate[required,custom[email]]" id="input_email" placeholder="Email *">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="input_subject">Phone</label>
         <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="input_phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="uploaded_file">Select A File To Upload:</label>
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only" for="input_message">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control validate[required]" rows="7" id="input_message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Send</button>
      <span class="loading-spinner" style="display:none;"></span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base your code on the examples provided with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), particularly [the basic contact form example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps). It looks like you've used an obsolete one from elsewhere, and there are a lot of basic mistakes.

*Never* use a user-supplied address as the From address. It is forgery and will result in your messages not being delivered as you will fail SPF checks. Put your address as the from address and the submitter's address as a reply-to address.

The way you're handling the uploaded file is also wrong - [refer to the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). You're trusting user input again, and so are potentially vulnerable there; you must check the uploaded file using `is_uploaded_file` or `move_uploaded_file` - the example called [send_file_upload](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) shows how to handle uploads safely.

```
$target_dir = "/uploads/";
```

This is not a relative path - unless `/uploads` really exists at the root of your file system (which is unlikely), your path will be wrong. Construct it as a relative path, or figure out where you're starting from, e.g. one of these:

```
$target_dir = "./uploads/";
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/uploads/";
```

Lastly, PHPMailer's methods usually return true on success, so you can check whether e.g. the call to `addAttachment` has succeeded or not.